An inequality related to BMO on [0,1]
Suppose that $b\in L^1[0,1]$, and that $I$ is a subinterval of $[0,1]$ centered at $s_0$. we denote by $\widetilde{I}$ the double of $I$, namely, the interval centered at $s_0$ with length $2|I|$.
I want to show that there exists universal constant $C>0$, such that
\begin{align}
|I| \cdot\int_{[0,1]\setminus\widetilde{I}}\frac{|b(t)-b_I|}{|t-s_0|^2}dt \leq C\|b\|_{BMO},
\end{align} where $$b_I:=\frac{1}{|I|}\int_{I} b(t) dt.$$

This claim appears at the beginning of p. 946 of the paper by S. Janson, J. Peetre, and S. Semmes, titled "On the action of Hankel and Toeplitz operators on some function spaces," Duke Math. J, 1984. The paper states that one can prove the above inequality using the standard doubling argument, but I have not been successful. Some of my simple observations are listed below:

One can replace $b_I$ by $b_{\widetilde{I}}$ because $$|I| \cdot\int_{[0,1]\setminus\widetilde{I}}\frac{|b_{\widetilde{I}}-b_I|}{|t-s_0|^2}dt \leq C\|b\|_{BMO}.$$
If we use the estimate $$|t-s_0|\geq |I|$$ for $t$ outside of $\widetilde{I}$. Then we need to show
$$\frac{1}{|I|}\int_{[0,1]\setminus\widetilde{I}} |b(t)-b_I|dt \leq C\|b\|_{BMO}.$$ Unfortunately, this does not seem to hold when $|I|$ is small.


Any help or hint? Thanks.

It seems should break $[0,1]$ in to the dyadic intervals $I$, $2I-I$, $4I-2I$, etc. And then bound the integral on each part by BMO norm.

We need the following elementary proposition which can be found in text book involving the theory of $BMO$:

Proposition 1: Let $I$ and $J$ be two arcs such that $I\subseteq J$ and $|J|\leq 2|I|$. Then the following inequality holds:
$$|b_J-b_I| \leq 2 \|b\|_{BMO}.$$ In particular, for any integer $k\geq 0$, we have $$|b_{2^k I}-b_I| \leq 2k \|b\|_{BMO},$$ where $2^kI $ denotes the arc with same center as $I$ and length $2^k|I|$.
A proof of the proposition 1 is presented (for the sake of completeness):
For the first inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
|b_J-b_I|&= \bigg|\frac{1}{|I|}\int_{I} b -b_J\bigg|\leq \frac{1}{|I|}\int_{I} |b -b_J|\\
&\leq \frac{2}{|J|}\int_{J} |b -b_J|\leq 2\|b\|_{BMO}.
\end{align*}
The second one can be obtained by iteratively. Indeed,
\begin{align}
|b_{2^k I}-b_I| \leq \sum_{n=1}^k \big|b_{2^n I} -b_{2^{n-1} I}\big|\leq 2k \|b\|_{BMO}.
\end{align}

Proof. For integers $k\geq 0$, we define $I_k=2^kI,$ (perhaps $I_k=[0,1]$) and $J_k=I_k\setminus I_{k-1}$, $k\geq 1$. Clearly, $2|J_k| = |I_k|=2^k|I|$ and
\begin{align}
[0,1]\setminus \widetilde{I}= \bigsqcup_{k\geq 2} J_k.
\end{align}
Moreover, there exist universal constants $c$ and $C$ such that for any $k\geq 2$ and $t \in J_k$,
\begin{align}
c \,2^{k}|I| \leq |t-s_0| \leq C\,2^{k}|I|.
\end{align}
Breaking the integral $\int_{[0,1]\setminus \widetilde{I}}$ into $\sum_{k\geq 2} \int_{J_k}$, substituting the bound for $|t-s_0|$, and then applying the triangle inequality $|b-b_I| \leq |b-b_{I_k}|+ |b_{I_k}-b_I|$ on each term successively, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\int_{[0,1]\setminus \widetilde{I}} \frac{|b(t)-b_I|}{|t-t_0|^2} dt&\leq \sum_{k\geq2}  \int_{J_k} \frac{|b(t)-b_{I}|}{|t-s_0|^2} dt\\
&\lesssim \sum_{k\geq2} 2^{-2k}|I|^{-2}  \int_{J_k} |b(t)-b_{I}| dt\\
&\leq \sum_{k\geq2} 2^{-2k}|I|^{-2} \bigg( \int_{J_k} |b(t)-b_{I_k}| dt+ \int_{J_k} |b_{I_k}-b_{I}| dt\bigg)\\
&\leq \sum_{k\geq2} 2^{-2k}|I|^{-2} \bigg( \int_{I_k} |b(t)-b_{I_k}| dt+  |J_k| \cdot |b_{I_k}-b_{I}|\bigg)
\end{align*}
By above Proposition, the last summation does not exceed
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k\geq2} 2^{-2k}|I|^{-2} \bigg( 2^k|I|\cdot  \|b\|_{BMO} +  2^k |I| \cdot 2k \| b\|_{BMO}\bigg)\\
\leq &\sum_{k\geq2} 2^{-k}|I|^{-1}(2k+1) \|b\|_{BMO}.
\end{align*}
Since the series $\sum_{k\geq 2} 2^{-k}(2k+1)$ convergence, this completes the proof.
